# NodeJS Shopify Integration

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify

I have a client that wants to incorporate Shopify to the site I’m building for him.

I plan on using a sub domain to link his Shopify account to the site, so shop.example.com

So when a user clicks on the SHOP link in the nav bar they will be brought to the Shopify page to do their shopping.

My question is, I have a login system. Do I pass the credentials to Shopify so that it knows which user is now shopping or will the user have to login there (at Shopify) as well?  I hope they won’t have to login on example.com and then login at shop.example.com as well.

Does anyone have a better solution to link a node js app to Shopify?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Shopify has a multiplass functionality that is available to **Shopify Plus** accounts only, that can do this for you.

More on that here: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/plus/multipass

Please note that Shopify Plus accounts are around $1000/mo so it's not for small stores. (depends on your client store)

Another option is to use a single login app like https://apps.shopify.com/single-sign-onsso (haven't tested it, it was recommended to me when I had an inquiry for SSO)

There is no Shopify API (for the none-plus stores) that will handle this for you so you will need a lot imagination to handle and secure this if you plan to do it fully custom.

Comment: My client wants to sell a couple t-shirts etc. There is a buy now option that Shopify offers for $9/month, or you can create a storefront for $29/month. 

From their website: https://www.shopify.ca/pricing?&term=how%20much%20does%20shopify%20cost&Network=Search&SiteTarget=&mt=e&adid=328331668253&adpos=&CampaignId=1690202562&branded_enterprise=1&BOID=brand&gclid=CjwKCAiAgJWABhArEiwAmNVTBzW2cTu979V28f5sBi7hd4dh6Jt7oUjFb22KcPctwsLupiy0BLuC1xoCQYMQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds
Monthly price
USD
$29
per month
/mo
USD
$79 
per month
/mo
USD
$299 
per month
/mo

Comment: Anyhow, the question is once I setup the shopify storefront, how do users from my site connect with the shopify store? Will they have to login to shopify or can I use their login credentials from my site, and send that to shopify?

Comment: @xar86413 they need to login to Shopify as well, the logins will be separate.